# Joomla 3 get user id

Tags: joomla

I have this code in folder myjoomla/myscript/

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."" ); 
define( 'DS','/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS. 'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require(JPATH_BASE.DS.'libraries/joomla/factory.php');

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

jimport( 'joomla.session.session' );
$session                =& JFactory::getSession();

$user =& JFactory::getUser();
echo "id:".$user->id;
```

I print JPATH_BASE and it ok. But no print  id, only print "0". I login ok in joomla. This ok in localhost, but in server no ok.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like extremely old code.  Are you working on Joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed, it's like old code. New code can be look like following,

```
<?php
if (!defined('_JEXEC'))
{
    // Initialize Joomla framework
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
}

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php'))
{
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}
if (!defined('JPATH_BASE'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
}
if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Get the framework.
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();

$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo "id:".$user->id;
```

Note: Tested your code on both local and live it was working for me. But not really sure why it's not work in your live environment. But your code is indeed old.

Comment: Thanks Gunjan, your code is ok and my code is ok, the problem is acces to joomla using "www" and acces no using "www"... i have two sessions diferents, one for "www.mysite.com" y other session for "mysite.com"